# -Wpedantic wrong type argument to increment after casting

Tags: c, gcc, pointer-arithmetic, gcc-pedantic

I have a code like

```
while (n--)
{
  *((char*)dest++) = *((char*)src++);
}
```

where `dest` and `src` are void pointers and `n` a size. The goal is to re-implement a memcpy function. When compiling this code with gcc, everything works great, but when I add the `-Wpedantic` flag I have four warnings "wrong type argument to increment".

Google tells me that it happens when trying to use arithmetic on void pointers, because gcc treats void type as being a 1 byte type in this case, but legacy compilers shoud not. I then have to cast the pointer to a char pointer but as you can see I already did it!

Any idea?

Comment: `*(((long*)dest)++) = *(((long*)src)++);`

Comment: I thought of it too, but then I have an error "lvalue required as increment operand"

Comment: you can do the increment separately: `dest = (long*)dest + 1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting (void) `dest` and `src` to `unsigned char *` *before* you use them gives the cleanest code (at the cost of two pointer variables on the stack).

```
unsigned char * dest_p = (unsigned char *)dest;
unsigned char * src_p  = (unsigned char *)src;

while ( n-- )
{
    *dest_p++ = *source_p++;
}
```

(Why `unsigned`? Because that's how the standard explicitly defines it. ;-) )

Comment: Yes, you are right, in fact I copied the just a part of the code where I verify that the data I have to copy is word-aligned, if not I use char type. I will fix it now in the post.

Comment: the ++ has a higher precedence than the cast, so the increment goes to the void pointer, which is not allowed

Comment: @Thüzhen: Adapted answer to fit your edit. Sorry, I thought the *reason* for the warning was somewhat obvious... ;-)

Comment: Why `*(((long*)dest)++) = *(((long*)src)++);` does not work then?

Comment: @Thüzhen: Because you're doing arithmetics on a temporary?

Comment: Oh, you mean that since I do the cast in the loop, the casted variable is temporary (and "dies" at the end of the loop) and thus does not hold the incremented value?

Comment: @Thüzhen: No. I mean that `((long*)dest)` is not an lvalue ("temporary" is perhaps the wrong word here, I'm not sure about the exact language lawyer legalese on this point). You can `dest++`, and you can `dest_p++` (in my code example), but you cannot `++` a *cast* pointer.