# Wrong type argument to increment

Tags: c, pointers

In the following dummy example, I get a warning and I don't understand how I can get rid of it without explicitly define a pointer with `int *_str = (int*)str`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void foo(void *str, int c, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        *((int*)str++) = c;
}
```

Here is what I get in `gcc`:

```
gcc -c -std=c99 -Wpointer-arith test.c
test.c: In function ‘mymemset’:
test.c:7:20: warning: wrong type argument to increment [-Wpointer-arith]
         *((int*)str++) = c;
                    ^
```

What's wrong with my code?

**NOTE**

I know this question is quite similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033338/wpedantic-wrong-type-argument-to-increment-after-casting), but it doesn't explain why I cannot do it and why I get an error.

Comment: `*((int*)str++) = c;` --> `*((int*)(str)+i) = c;`

Comment: The `++` operator has higher precedence than the cast to `int *`.  But *why* are you trying to stuff so much into so few characters?  Are you competing in an obfuscated code contest?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am curious and I think that using a third variable would give a more obfuscated code.

Comment: @nowox Having to count and match parenthesis while keeping track of operator precedence is a lot harder than clearly changing the variable type from `void *` to `int *` before operating on it.  And I hope this version of `memset()` you're writing isn't supposed to be a direct replacement for the standard `memset()` - think about what happens if `sizeof(int)` isn't equal to 1.  Then read the documentation for `memset()`.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew, just add `int* pInt = (int*)str;` before the loop and get rid of the cast. If you have to ask this question on SO, for *your own code*, then it's a pretty clear indicator the code is already obfuscated, and future maintainers will have even more problems. `*pInt++ = c;` is many times easier for a human to parse.

Comment: Btw, reinventing `memset` is a bad idea. Many C programmers realize they can shorten their loop times by assigning words instead of bytes, but these same programmers forget about alignment issues.

Comment: Note that the "fixed" code as suggested by LPs and others, violates the strict aliasing rule for some types of input buffer (e.g. `char buf[100];`) and also may be an alignment violation for some inputs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-Wpedantic wrong type argument to increment after casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033338/wpedantic-wrong-type-argument-to-increment-after-casting)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't want to reinvent memset I just used this name to not have the remark "Why don't you use `int*` for the first argument. As I said I is a dummy function.

Comment: @Groo It is not a duplicate because the duplicate also mentioned on my question doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: @nowox: same principles still apply, violation of strict aliasing and issues with addresses which are not aligned to `int`.

Comment: @nowox the suggested duplicate does answer it, if you change `char` to `int`. I don't really think we need a separate question for each possible data type making this mistake..

Comment: @nowox: to quote the answer: "Casting (void) dest and src to (...) *before* you use them gives the cleanest code". Just ignore the part which I placed in parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You felt into a X-Y problem because you misunderstood what `*((int*)str++) = c` is supposed to do. So your question is not about `void` arithmetic, but a `lvalue` post-increment.

Let's put the `void` issue apart for a while and consider `int64_t` and `int32_t` which have a size of 8 and 4 on a 32-bit architecture byte addressable. In short, two types with a different size.

If you want to cast `int32_t*` into `int64_t*`, assign to it a value and post increment the pointer it, you may have written as follow (inspirated from your example):

```
int32_t* p = &value;
*((int64_t*)p++) = 42;
```

According to the operator [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) the order execution is:

1. Take p
2. Save it for post-increment as a int32_t*
3. Cast it to int64_t*
4. Dereference it and assign 42 as a int64_t
5. Post increment p

This example builds perfectly, but it is not doing what you think it does. What to want is to post-increment the cast pointer. So you need one more parenthesis:

```
*(((int64_t*)p)++) = 42;
```

This time, you will get an error because `((int64_t*)p)` is considered as a `lvalue` and thus it cannot be modified.

In this particular case you absolutely need a third variable to do the trick.

This is exactly the same with your `void` pointer.

Comment: `*((*(int64_t **)&p)++) = 42;`?

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a pointer to `void`. Since `void` is well, void, and has no size, how could the poor compiler possibly understand what you mean by `str++`?

`str++` is supposed to make `str` point to the next object, but since the type `void` cannot be the type of any object `str++` is meaningless.

Though you cast to int *, ++ is more "binding" (the word "precedence" confuses here) than the cast.

Comment: Technically it's a constraint violation